# Group of order $2^2 \cdot 3^n$, $n \geq 1$.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $2^2 \cdot 3^n$, with $n \geq 1$. The objective is to show that there is a normal subgroup of order $3^n$ **or** $3^{n-1}$; I can do the first part using the Sylow Theorems, but can't even tink about the second one. How to proceed?

Comment: What does **or** mean here? Do you mean there is a normal subgroup of order $3^n$ **and** there is a normal subgroup of order $3^{n - 1}$?

Comment: You have only asked one question so it is unclear what you mean by the first part and the second part.

Comment: @WhatsUp, no, the normal subgroup has order $3^n$ or it has order $3^{n-1}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I can show that there is a normal subgroup of order $3^n$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You seem to be confused about what you are trying to prove. You have to show that either there is a normal subgroup of order $3^n$, or there is a normal subgroup of order $3^{n-1}$ (which is exactly what you said in your previous comment to WhatsUp). There is no first and second part to this question.

Comment: @DerekHolt that happens when you think in portuguese then translate to english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that the number of $3$-sylow groups  $n_3 =1 \mod 3$, and $n_3 = [ G: N_G(P)]\leq [G:P] = 4$, where $P$ is some $3$-sylow group. If $n_3 =1$ we are done as the single $3$-Sylow is fixed by automorphisms and therefore is normal.

Otherwise, if $n_3 =4$, $G$ acts (by conjugation) as permutations of the four $3$-Sylows, i.e. we have a map $\varphi: G \to S_4$, since conjugation acts transitively on the $3$-Sylows, its image must have order divisible by 4 (you cant act transitively on four elements otherwise), Since $\lvert S_4\rvert = 3 \cdot 8$, there are only two possibilities, $\lvert im(\varphi)\rvert = 4, 12$ and since $\lvert im(\varphi) \rvert \lvert ker(\varphi)\rvert = \lvert G \rvert = 4 \cdot 3^n$, we have that the kernel of $\varphi$ must have $3^n$ or $3^{n-1}$ elements, since we started by the asumption that we have four $3$-Sylows, we can't have a normal subgroup of order $3^n$, the kernel of that map must be a normal subgroup of order $3^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I got some questions: First, the map $\phi$ is a homomorphism? Second, isn't $\left| S_{4} \right| = 24 = 4.6$? Third, why we can affirm that $\left|im(\phi) \right| = 4,12$?

Comment: My mistake, edited to be $8 \cdot 3$.  we can affirm that about the image because the image has to have a subgroup of order 4, but since 8 doesnt divide the order of $G$ 8 can't divide the order of the image and that are the only options.

Comment: Now I‘ve got it! Thank you!